# remove a null element from an array of records in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created a composite type in postgres:
`create type fkData as (table_varchar, constraint_name varchar, constraint_def text);`

A function populates an array of fkdata from a list of tables that have foreign key dependencies:

```
create or replace function get_fk(tblnm character varying) returns fkData[] language 'plpgsql'
    as $BODY$
    declare cons fkData[];
    with fk as (select conrelid as table_name, conname as foreign_key, pg_get_constraintdef(oid) as 
        condef
        from pg_constraint
        where contype = 'f'
          and connamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
          and conname like concat('%',tblnm,'%')
        order by conrelid::regclass, contype DESC)
    select array_agg(row(table_name, foreign_key, condef))  into cons
    from fk;
    return cons;
    end;
    $BODY$;
```

now for the 64K question.  One table in my list has no FK dependencies, and the function returns a null array element that causes an error in my loop through the array of fk defs.  I am having a hard time filtering OR removing the null element.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out the null elements from the array returned by your function, you can use the array_remove function provided by PostgreSQL. Here's an updated version of your function that includes the filtering:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_fk(tblnm CHARACTER VARYING) 
  RETURNS fkData[] 
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
AS 
$BODY$ 
DECLARE 
  cons fkData[]; 
BEGIN 
  WITH fk AS (
    SELECT conrelid AS table_name, 
           conname AS foreign_key, 
           pg_get_constraintdef(oid) AS condef 
    FROM pg_constraint 
    WHERE contype = 'f' 
      AND connamespace = 'public'::regnamespace 
      AND conname LIKE concat('%', tblnm, '%') 
    ORDER BY conrelid::regclass, contype DESC
  ) 
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(row(table_name, foreign_key, condef)) INTO cons FROM fk; 
  
  cons := array_remove(cons, NULL); -- Filter out null elements
  
  RETURN cons; 
END; 
$BODY$;
```

In this updated version, the array_remove function is used to remove any null elements from the cons array before returning it. This ensures that you won't encounter null values during your loop through the array.

By applying the array_remove function, the null elements are filtered out, and you will only have non-null elements in the resulting array.